# Flex Datagrid display item editor on hover

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have a datagrid and I want to display an item editor (text input) when the mouse is over the cells.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [editedItemPosition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#editedItemPosition) property for this.

> Setting this property scrolls the item into view and dispatches the `itemEditBegin` event to open an item editor on the specified item renderer.

Listen to `itemRollOver` event and set the `editedItemPosition` property from there.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" itemRollOver="startEdit(event)" other="attributes">
```

Script:

```
private function startEdit(event:ListEvent):void
{
    var c:Number = event.columnIndex;
    var r:Number = event.rowIndex;
    dg.editedItemPosition = {columnIndex:c, rowIndex:r};
}
```